# phonegap single button press the correct way without multitouch interfering

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, button, locking

I am developing a phonegap app currently testing on an iphone. What i want to do is simple. I want to press a button and only that button which i am pressing must be pressed. I want to prevent the user from pressing more then one button at the same time. To do this according to apples guideline, you should disable all other buttons when the target buttons is pressed. The problem for me is that if you keep tabbing two buttons on the exact same time eventually, then both of the buttons are pressed. There arent locks in javascript as far as i know, and also i have tried to use a variable as a lock but it still doenst work. I have this code which can be tested on an iphone to replicate the problem. My question is how do you program button presses the right way?

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>

      <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){

               CreateEvents();
           }); //end ready function

           function CreateEvents()
           {

                 $('.divs').on('touchstart', function(){

               $('.divs').not(this).off();
                  $(this).css('background-color','red');

               });



               $('.divs').on('touchend', function(){

                  $(this).css('background-color','green');
                  setTimeout(function(){
                        CreateEvents();

                        }, 300);

               });


               }
      </script>
<style>
 .divs{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:green;

}
 </style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="divs">
div1
</div>

<div class="divs">
div2
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the right way to press buttons to make sure only one is pressed at a time.

```
   $(".divs").on('touchstart', function(event){
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        event.preventDefault();

                        if(event.handled !== true) {

                                    $('.divs').not(this).off();
                                      $(this).css('background-color','red');

                            event.handled = true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                });
            $(".divs").on('touchend', function(event){
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        event.preventDefault();

                        if(event.handled !== true) {

                                     $(this).css('background-color','green');
                                     CreateEvents();

                            event.handled = true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                });
```

However its important to notice that if you use both touch events and mouse click events, some devices will make a double click because they register the touch both as a click and a touch event. This method apparently should prevent that also, however it really doesnt. This is called "ghostclick" and there should be plugins to fix this, but the easiest way it just to go with either touch events or mouse click events.

It would still be nice to see other examples of how people manage these problems in your own apps??